# Heroku PostgreSQL Database How To Start

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am attempting to make a database using Heroku's PostgreSQL, but I do not really understand how it works, or how to really begin. My goal is to make a level system for discord.js where I can store things such as userid, username, xp and levels. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: Start by learning the basics of relational databases, and some sql. Apart from fiddling around in an sql shell, learn about the sql libraries your backend's programming language offers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)